# Get data in between 2 values with where condition in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to PowerBI and i need help from experts like you..

I am connecting MySQL db and geeting the data.

I am attaching sample data of csv [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sp3go0r7oiicns9/sample.csv?dl=0) which was exported from table visual.

I have versions from 0.1 to 2.0(i.e 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ..... 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, .... 2.0) for each quotations. i.e each quotations can have multiple versions from 0.1 to 2.1

My desired table should be,

1. I want to show only those quoations which have version 1.0 within  version (0.1 to <=1.0) version
   I want to show minimum version and maximum version(1.0) for each quotation and days between min version date and version 1.0 date
2. I want to show only those quoatations which have version 2.0 within version (1.1 to <=2.0) version
   I want to show minimum version and maximum version(2.0) for each quotation and days between min version date and version 2.0 date

Sample output:

1. I want to show the quoations which have version 1.0 within  version (0.1 to <=1.0) version.I want to show minimum version and maximum version(1.0) for each quotation and days between min version date and version 1.0 date

> ```
>  Quation#  |  min version | max version|  duration 
>  quote1       0.1              1.0           10 days
>   quote3       0.3              1.0          3 days
> ```

2. I want to show the quoatations which have version 2.0 within version (1.1 to <=2.0) version.  I want to show minimum version and maximum version(2.0) for each quotation and days between min version date and version 2.0 date

> ```
> Quation#  |  min version | max version|  duration  
> quote2       1.1              2.0          4 days 
> quote3       1.3              2.0          8 days
> ```

Please share pbix file if you get the output.

Please help me to achieve this. Thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow the steps:

Make a group based on the version:

[image]
This can also be made using DAX but is much easier like this (if you want I can send you the DAX formula).

Create the following Measure:

```
Duration = 
DATEDIFF (
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( 'sample'[businessDate] ),
    ALLSELECTED ( 'sample'[businessDate] )
),
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'sample'[businessDate] ),
    ALLSELECTED ( 'sample'[businessDate] )
),
DAY)
```

Add in a table visual the following fields:
QuoteNo - Don't summarize
Version - First version (rename to min version)
Version - Last version (rename to max version)
Duration
versions(group) - reduce the size of the column until is hidden
 [image]
Final version:

Add this measure to your table and the add it to the filters on the table result is as presented:

```
Validation =
IF (
    MAX ( 'sample'[version] ) = INT ( MAX ( 'sample'[version] ) )
       = TRUE (),
    1,
    0
 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a third comparison into your query to check if there is a row for the current Quote# with a version of 1.0. With that in mind, I would edit your current query to be the following.

```
Bucket = 'prod_check dw_proposal'[version] >= 0.1 &&
    'prod_check dw_proposal'[version] < 1.1 &&
    CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('prod_check dw_proposal'), 
        FILTER('prod_check dw_proposal', 
            'prod_check dw_proposal'[Quote#] = EARLIER('prod_check dw_proposal'[Quote#]) && 
            'prod_check dw_proposal'[version] = 1.0
        )
    ) = 1
```

Please let me know if any part of the formula is confusing.

Comment: Hi.. i have updated question to make you understand. Please check and help me out to make this achievable. Waiting for your response eagerly

Comment: my skype id is mehaboob57 sir. please ping me there. i will be waiting for u

Comment: @user3599302 - Since your question has completely changed, it will be some work to answer the new question. Additionally, you don't have any sample data in the question. Please post some data in your question and I can start working on a solution for you.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sp3go0r7oiicns9/sample.csv?dl=0 this is the sample data sir